# Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

I currently have a View in MVC where I pass a single set of data to the view. However, I've come across a problem where I am having to use a LINQ query within a For Each loop in the View to pull out additional information from a SQL View of data from another DB.

The error I'm getting is **Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree**.

The particular snippet I'm encountering the error on is:

```
          <%
            For Each oCall In ViewData.Model
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td width="290"><a href="/Calls/Details/<%=oCall.CallID %>"><%=oCall.CallSubject %></a></td>
                    <td width="140"><%=oCall.CallReference %></td>
                    <td width="130"><%=oCall.CallType.CallTypeName %></td>
                    <td width="150"><%=oCall.DateOpened %></td>
                    <%
                        Dim assigned As String
                        Dim db As New CustomerServicesModelDataContext

                        Dim tStore = (From a In db.vStores _
                                      Where a.CompanyID = oCall.CompanyID _
                                      And a.StoreNumber = oCall.StoreID _
                                      Select a).SingleOrDefault()
                        assigned = tStore.Store
                        %>
                    <td width="175">
                        <%= assigned%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%
            Next

            %>
```

The error happens twice. First on oCall.CompanyID and then on oCall.StoreID.

Have I missed something?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Database access in your views!?!?!?!  The horror!

Comment: I know, it's just a quick and dirty work around that I'll come back to fix later when I have the time to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liam,

I've seen this happen before and i've got around it by assigning the values of oCall.CompanyID and oCall.StoreID to variables i.e.:

```
int companyId = oCall.CompanyID;
int storeId = oCall.StoreID;
```

then plug that into your linq expression. basically, the issue is in trying to resolve the two syncronys calls at the same time.

hope this helps.

jim

Comment: It's gotten me around that problem, however, led me to another.

I now receive the error Method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' has no supported translation to SQL'

Comment: ok, no problem, try using this instead: a.CompanyID.Equals(
companyId) And a.StoreNumber.Equals(storeId).

Comment: Liam - nice one. hope you get around to refactoring that logic into your controller soon :-). all the best..